# Getting an appended href link with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append, local-storage

I am trying to get a link from an appended element.

The link is appended like so:

```
var imdbPointer = "https://www.imdb.com/title/" + data.imdb_id
imdbLink.empty()
imdbLink.append("<a href='" + imdbPointer + "'>" + "IMDB - " + data.original_title  + "</a>")
```

This essentially generates an imdb link for me. I was previously using

`var storeIMDBLink = $( "a" ).attr( "href")` This code successfuly got me the link when it was the only href one the page, however it grabs the first href it finds.

How can I grab a specific href link from this appended element?

Comment: At what point(eg. onclick) will you want to grab the href attr of the link appended

Comment: I'd suggest using [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and properly creating an element to retrieve data from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get there with some hackiness.

`var storeIMDBLink = $(this).parent().siblings('#imdb-link').children().attr( "href")`

Both the imdb link and button that stored it were appended to the same UL